# <Model>.last works when in spec/integration/... but fails/errors when in spec/features/...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Rails 4.0.0; RSpec 2.14.x; Capybara 2.1.0

Refactoring/reorganizing some specs in the green.

```
describe 'Visiting propane_fill_path' do
  shared_examples_for 'with a recorded fill' do |fill_sym|
    context 'when not signed in' do
      include_examples 'visiting redirects to user sign in', :propane_fill_path, Fill.last
    ...
```

works when in `spec/integration/...`; but when I move it to `spec/features/...` (no other files moved, changed, *etc*), it fails with

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"propane/fills", :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

So with all the same `before()`s, `let()`/`let!()`s, *etc*., `Fill.last` acts differently in this different directory?

No effect when I change `describe` to `feature` (*e.g.*, to match the `:type` to the location?)

Is spec path meant to change execution behavior?

TIA

Comment: Did you create a Fill prior to the test? If you use database_cleaner and delete all your Fill records, you won't have a Fill record to pass to your url. Hence: missing required keys :id

Comment: @mathieugagne -- Yes - 1) it passed when in the other directory; 2) it passes when I change `Fill.last` to `fill_sym` (otherwise used elsewhere in the `shared_examples_for` group); but still wondering why/how the spec's path is significant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is explained in [this paragraph from rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs)

> Request specs live in spec/requests, spec/api and spec/integration, and mix in behavior ActionDispatch::Integration::Runner, which is the basis for Rails' integration tests. The intent is to specify one or more request/response cycles from end to end using a black box approach.

[Capybara-based specs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/Capybara.md) should stay in `spec/features` because in this way Capybara::DSL is included.

However keep in mind that the behavior may not be the same. `spec/features` does not mix the entire Rails environment. If you rely on some boot feature to populate the `Fill` table, it may not work.

In any case, it's not advisable to populate it globally. Use `before` or `set` to setup your test.